# Visual Studio Code mac os x .net build and deploy

Tags: asp.net, .net, macos, msbuild, webdeploy

Is it possible to 
1. Build C# projects with MSBuild on mac in VS Code
2. Debug asp.net apps with mono dev server
3. Deploy with oneclickdeploy on remote server
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this might be a little late for you, but maybe this will help.

[Develop and Deploy ASP.NET 5 Apps on Mac OS X](http://blog.tonysneed.com/2015/05/25/develop-and-deploy-asp-net-5-apps-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: Thanks, it helped alot!

Comment: That describes the first two parts - how to create and debug, but says nothing about deployment to a remote server.